# Bazel list of build artifacts

Tags: bazel

How to list the artifacts that were built after a `bazel build //...`?

The `bazel query` explores the dependencies, but I would like to list the actual artifacts that were built, taking into account the cache (exclude those that had a cache hit).

(building golang binaries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple solutions to this problem. The first is to use the `--show_result` flag. This one is a little funny as it accepts an integer (i.e. give me up to this many results). So just give it a really large number (> the total number of targets). e.g.

`bazel build //... --show_result=10000000000000`

This will print out a list of all the artifacts that were cached, built or failed build (if you combine it with `--keep_going` otherwise the build will stop on the first failure).

If you need more granular artifact information from the build graph (i.e. intermediate artifacts). You could use bazel's action query system e.g.

`bazel aquery //...`

This will give you a list of all the actions and corresponding input/output artifacts for each action (including intermediate artifacts). Depending on your code base this could potentially be a huge output. But it won't give you any information about cache hits etc. The action graph is evaluated before the build, so it doesn't have that information yet.

So there isn't one command that does exactly what you are after but perhaps combining the two will give you what your after.